# Automated registration email

Tags: asp.net, email, triggers, registration, sitefinity

To be short -

- User registers for the site
- An email is sent to the user confirming their registration

I am using :

- Asp.net 3.5(C#)
- Sitefinity as a CMS
- MS SQL 2008 server r2

My question is what is the best way to automatically send the email?

Should it be done in ASP.net or as a database trigger using something like xp_sendmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to simplicity; then ASP.NET Membership system should suffice.  There's bunch of videos on how to setup user registration and email confirmation on ASP.NET website:

ASP.NET Membership
http://www.asp.net/learn/security-videos/video-389.aspx

Setup email registration confirmation
http://www.asp.net/security/videos/implement-the-registration-verification-pattern

If I read correctly, Sitefinity is built on top of ASP.NET's existing membership system.  So integration should not be that difficult.

Comment: Membership! Thanks you - this has really set me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem.  If this answer is helpful, please click on the check on the left.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would always say in ASP.NET. Your code should be in control of everything like that.

As soon as you put it in the database you will start building problems for the future. I.e. when you move database with the sys admin remember this needs doing etc. In code you will have your SMTP server in the configs so it should always be manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you implement the e-mail notification in ASP.NET as already suggested. You can leverage the emailing features of the .NET framework. Sitefinity is built-on top of .NET and you can use already existing code to implement the desired e-mailing feature.